# Javascript window.open does nothing, produces no error

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been asked to have it where a new window is produced every time a user loads a page. So I've created the following code located in the  tag...

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            function popup(mylink, windowname) {
                if (! window.focus) return true;

                var href;

                if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') {
                    href = mylink;
                } else {
                    href = mylink.href;
                    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200');
                }

                return false;
            }
        </SCRIPT>
```

and the onLoad function to create the popup on page load

```
<body onLoad="popup('http://yahoo.com', 'ad')">
```

However, nothing happens. No tab is created, no new window is created, and when viewing through firebug, no error is produced. Attempted this on chrome, firefox and IE9 with the same results, with none of the browsers complaining they've blocked a popup window. Am I missing something incredibly simple here?

Comment: *"So I've been asked to have it where a new window is produced every time a user loads a page."* Say no. Then explain why.

Comment: I did. The response was "do it, or we'll find someone that will". Sadly not everyone works in a wonderful work environment.

Comment: @ canadian: Well, the problem is, even if you do the code for them, it won't work. The browsers will prevent the pop-up. Good luck, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. I'll need it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mylink` is a string (and it is, in your example), you never call `window.open`:

```
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') {
    // Code takes this path
    href = mylink;
} else {
    // Not this one
    href = mylink.href;
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200');
}
```

---

Having said that: If you fix that, you *will* get the warning/error from pop-up blockers. Browsers prevent sites from opening pop-ups except in direct response to a user action, like a click. Sites opening pop-ups on page load is one of the reasons for that.

---

Side note: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. No need for parens around the operand.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. javascript isn't my forte so as expected I missed something simple. And ya having this functionality isn't my idea, but you do what the folks giving you money want. Thanks for the response.